# Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to compile my app in flutter, but when I do it, I get the following error in the console.
I tried running `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get` but it doesn't seem to work

Warning: elemento inesperado (URI:"", local:"base-extension"). Los elementos esperados son <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/firebase_app.dart:18:25: Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'.
FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends(_delegate);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.`

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 16s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          262.0s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
``
[image: console error]

I tried running flutter clean and then flutter pub get but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 2):

Go to dependencies in `pubspec.yaml` and click on 'pub upgrade' ... the last versions of dependencies will appear in terminal ... increase your firebase packages to the new versions ... I try it and it works with me.

Answer (score 0):

According to this - https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9814 it's a problem with dependencies.

In my case I have first added old firebase_core dependencies and then overridden them to newest ones, but Android Studio did not delete old dependencies.
I have deleted the build folder from the main project folder, then I downloaded dependencies again in pubspec.yaml and code started working.

Answer (score 0):

I had macOS Monterey and upgrade to Ventrua worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Close project.
2. Go to project repository folder.
3. Delete all generated files, for example:

   - .dart_tool
   - .idea
   - .build
   - .flutter-plugins
   - .flutter-plugins-dependencies
   - .metadata
   - .packages
     Nothing should changed in your git changes due to .gitignore file
4. Open Android Studio again
5. Go to File->Invalidate Caches/Restart, then invalidate caches and restart

if your project structure is corrupted go to: File -> Close Project, close project and reopen it, it should be back to normal.

6. Run all the necessary scripts starting with:

- `flutter pub get`
- `dart pub get`

Answer (score -1):

Go to dependencies in pubspec.yaml and click on 'pub upgrade' ... the last versions of dependencies will appear in terminal ... increase your firebase packages to the new versions ... I try it and it works with me

This answer work with me too.